# How do I replicate the exact layout of the attached document?

Tags: html, css

[image]

Hi
The form is a word document and I have been trying to recreate it exactly as is with html but having difficulty unfotunately.

This is what I have so far. Perhaps, css is the reason why it isn't laying out correctly.

Thanks for your assistance.

CSS - Must have:

```
 <style type="text/css">
 table .mystyle
{
    border-width: 0 0 1px 1px;
    border-spacing: 0;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color:#000;
    width:900px;
}

.mystyle td, .mystyle th
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 4px;
    border-width: 1px 1px 0 0;
    border-style: solid;
    font-size:medium;
    border-color:#000;
}
   </style>
```

Current html:

```
  <table class="mystyle">
    <tr>
    <td style="width:50px;" class="style7">&nbsp;</td>
        <td style="width:158px;" class="style7">Milestone</td>
    <td style="width:158px;" class="style7">Owner</td>
        <td style="width:108px;white-space:nowrap;">
          <TABLE border="1">
             <TR>
               <TD colspan="2">Completion Date</TD>
            </TR>
            <TR>
              <TD>Target</TD>
              <TD>Actual</TD>
            </TR>
           </TABLE>
         </td>
        <td style="width:358px;" class="style7">Comments</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>

    </tr>
  </table>
```

Extreme left are Qtr 1 through Qtr4

[image]

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of what you've managed till now, it would help with us helping you faster.

Comment: What is the exact problem you've run into with what you have tried so far?  You are going down the correct path with nested tables.  It's just a matter at this point of fixing your specific issues then continuing on.

Comment: ok, pls give me a second to show get it and post it. Thanks

Comment: @Michael Uh, there's no reason why you should need more than a single table for this.

Comment: @cimmanon How would you split the completion date area???

Comment: I think it is the css throwing it off but we need the css for the borders.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key to laying out that table is using *rowspan* and *colspan* attributes.

http://tinker.io/174de/1

```
<table class="mystyle">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th rowspan="2">Quarter</th>
            <th rowspan="2">Milestone</th>
            <th rowspan="2">Owner</th>
            <th colspan="2">Completion Date</th>
            <th rowspan="2">Comments</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Target</th>
            <th>Actual</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th rowspan="3">Q1</th>
            <td>a</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>b</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>c</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th rowspan="3">Q2</th>
            <td>a</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>b</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>c</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You don't *have* to use the tbody element, but they're really helpful for styling rowspanned elements:  http://codepen.io/cimmanon/pen/KqoCs